# Remove drive letters via batch or vbs scripting

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-7

I am searching for a little batch or vbs script that does the following:

- Find the drives in a list of valid drive letters, e.g. ['c','d','e','f'], that have a specific drive name, e.g. 'BackupDrive'
- Remove the drive letters of the found drives so that they are no more displayed in Windows Explorer

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Remove the drive letter"? Do you need to unmap/disconnect the mapped drive?

Comment: Hi! Basically the same action that you could do in "Administrative Tools/Computer Management/Storage/Disk Management" if you select "Change Drive Letter and Paths" on the drive and click "Remove".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the command line tool "diskpart". As stated in the [official technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757491%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_CMD) if you know the volume name you can remove it with:

```
select volume <volume number>
remove letter=<Letter>
```

You can automate this either using a script file (as [documented here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614984.aspx)) with the exact commands, or by calling the exe with objShell.Exec on the shell object in vbscript and manipulating the stdin and stdout accordingly. An example for that can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/04/26/how-to-automate-a-command-line-utility-like-diskpart-vbscript.aspx). In your case this would probably be the better approach because you could do a "list volume" there and then parse the result for description and label and act accordingly. Afaik this is sadly the only way to get to the volume number, because it is not present in wmi or somewhere easier queryable.

Please keep in mind that diskpart is a VERY powerful tool, that can wipe whole partitions, so use it with caution.

Also note:

> You cannot remove the drive letters on system, boot, or paging
>   volumes. In addition, you cannot remove the drive letter for an OEM
>   partition, any GPT partition with an unrecognized GUID, or any of the
>   special, non-data, GPT partitions such as the EFI system partition.